# How do reload page when click item menu in Xamarin.Form Shell Flyout

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I'm using the Xamarin.Form Shell Flyout.

When click item menu, from the second time, the page don't reload.

How do reload page (reload data) when click item menu in Xamarin.Form Shell Flyout?

```
<FlyoutItem Route="animals" Title="Animals" FlyoutDisplayOptions="AsMultipleItems">
        <ShellContent Route="Monkeys" Title="Monkeys" Icon="tab_feed.png" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local:MonkeysPage}" />
</FlyoutItem>
```

[image]

Comment: That's the default behavior and the page won't be reload when you click menu item. You can try to reload data in OnAppearing method.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT  I done it. Thank you for help!

Comment: You use OnAppearing method to solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, I using OnAppearing method.

Comment: I just added an answer and  can you please accept it (click the ☑️ in the upper left corner of this answer ) so that we can help more people with same problem:)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  reload the page in the [OnAppearing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.page.onappearing?view=xamarin-forms)  method:).